# Adding Request Parameters for Authorization Url in spring.security.oauth2.client before redirect

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux

I currently have a Gateway application that uses Netty server, and OAuth2 along with the gateway. Currently, it is using `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository`, `@EnableWebFluxSecurity`, and `ServerHttpSecurity` to configure the security.

Currently, my application.yml looks like this:

```
spring:
  profiles: local
  autoconfigure: #TODO: track issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6314
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          azure:
            provider: azure
            client-id: ...
            client-secret: ...
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri-template: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: ...
        provider:
          azure:
            authorization-uri: https://login....com/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: https://login.com/oauth2/token
            user-info-uri: https://login.com/openid/userinfo
            jwk-set-uri: https://login.com/discovery/keys
            issuer-url: https://login.com/
            user-name-attribute: upn
```

I have a requirement to add a query parameter (in addition to defaults like scope and state). This may be something like

"https://login....com/oauth2/authorize?idp=IDP1"

I've already tried adding a filter to change location and add the query parameters, as well as adding the query parameter to the authorization-url in the yml file.

The latter results in the error: because of the fact that there are now 2 `?` in the url.

`Invalid character '=' for QUERY_PARAM in "true?response_type=code"`

```java
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${content.security.policy}")
    private String contentSecurityPolicy;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain configure(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        return http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and().oauth2Login()
                .and().headers().contentSecurityPolicy(contentSecurityPolicy).and()
                .and().build();
    }
```

```java
@Configuration
public class OAuthWebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        // (optional) explicitly opt into using the oauth2Login to provide an access token implicitly
        oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();
    }
```

build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    implementation 'org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:0.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.8'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.5-jre'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client', version: '2.1.5.RELEASE'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-security', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'com.microsoft.azure:adal4j:1.6.4'
}
```

EXPECTED:
The authorization URL is generated with the regular query parameters such as: redirect_uri, scope, state, and CUSTOM parameters such as `idp` in the example.

ACTUAL:
Adding to the yml file results in error `Invalid character '=' for QUERY_PARAM in "true?response_type=code"`
oauth2Login() on the ServerHttpSecurity has no easy way to override the authorization url. Is there any way?

Comment: I think its described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2Client-authorization-request-resolver

Comment: did you ever find a solution?  I have the same issue.  @przem 's answer is not for reactive apps, but for servlet apps.